# Immersion Etale if and only if Open Immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, schemes

I have a few questions about some steps in the proof of lemma 7 in Bosch's  "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" (page 379). Here the excerpt with red tagged problems:

[image]

Now my questions:

1. After having shown that matrix $(a_{ij})$ is locally invertible we conclude that the restrictions $t_1 |_W, ..., t_n |_W $ generate the ideal $\mathcal{I}$. But why does this provide that the zero section (?) $S \to \mathbb{A}^n _S$ to the open immersion $W \to \mathbb{A}^n _S$ end up with a morphism $U \to S$ such that it coincides with the restriction of $f$ to $U$. Why do we need here the condition that $t_1 |_W, ..., t_n |_W $ generate the ideal $\mathcal{I}$?

I don't see why we need this condition to make the construction as explained. Doesn't it just suffice that the $t_1 |_W, ..., t_n |_W $ are contained in $\mathcal{I}_W$?

2. What is here meant by "zero section" $S \to \mathbb{A}^n _S$? Is this just the canonical zero map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a_{ij}(z)$ invertible on the whole of $W$, the determinant of the matrix $(a_{ij})$ is a unit in $A'$. The relations $t_j|_W=\sum_i a_{ij} g_i$ then imply that $t_1|_W,\ldots,t_n|_W$ generate the same ideal as the $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ do.

You need that the elements $t_i|_W$ generate the ideal sheaf for being able to conclude that $f|_U$ is actually the base change of the open immersion $W\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_S$ along the zero section, which on global sections corresponds to the $R$-algebra morphism $s_0\colon R[t_1,\ldots,t_n]\to R$ sending $t_i$ to $0$.

On the level of rings you can argue as follows: Let $I$ denote the ideal of $A'$ cutting out $U$, i.e. $A=A'/I$. Then you have to show that the diagram involving the zero section $s_0$, the morphism $f|_U$ (on global sections), the projection $A\to A/I=A'$ and the morphism $R[t_1,\ldots,t_n]\to A'$ corresponding to the open immersion $W\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_S$ is a pushout in the category of rings. Explicitly, given ring morphisms $\varphi\colon A'\to C, \Phi\colon R\to C$ which coincide when being composed with the maps $R[t_1,\ldots,t_n]\to R$ and $R[t_1,\ldots,t_n]\to A'$, respectively, then you need that $I\subset \operatorname{ker}(\varphi)$. But since $s_0$ maps $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ to zero in $R$, you conclude that $\varphi$ maps $t_1|_W,\ldots,t_n|_W$ to zero in $A/I$. Since these generate the ideal $I$, you get the desired inclusion $I\subset \operatorname{ker}(\varphi)$.